# Prove if $f: A \rightarrow B, g: B \rightarrow C$, and $g \circ f: A\overset{1-1}{\rightarrow}C$, then $f: A \overset{1-1}{\rightarrow} B$

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-verification

Statement: If $f: A \rightarrow B, g: B \rightarrow C$, and $g o f: A\overset{1-1}{\rightarrow}C$, then $f: A \overset{1-1}{\rightarrow} B$

Here's my proof by contradiction.

Proof: Assume $f$ is not one-to-one, then $f(x_{1}) = f(x_{2})$ for some $x_{1}, x_{2} \in A$, and $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$. Thus, $g(f(x_{1})) = g(f(x_{2}))$ and where $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$. But this is a contradiction to the assumption that $g o f: A \overset{1-1}{\rightarrow} C$

Is my proof valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. It's generally a good idea, however, to not phrase it as a contradiction if there's a direct proof that's just as easy. So it's perhaps slightly better form to write something like

> Suppose that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Then we have $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2))$, and since $g \circ f$ is $1-1$, we see that $x_1 = x_2$. Hence $f$ is $1-1$.